# Replication from an SQL Server into memory of a process

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a couple of tables in a SQL Server database, most of them are updated only rarely, i.e. they are mostly-read.

In order not to have to go to the database every time I read an entry, what we have done is, on startup we load all tables completely into memory of our .net process (the data is small enough), and at intervals of 10 seconds we reread the whole thing and replace our in-memory representation of the data.

This in-memory representation of the data is then used for reading, and we don't have to go synchronously to the DB, unless we want to update the data.

Suffice to say this currently hand-coded process (for each table we have to write code that *SELECT ** and handles the received rows) is tedious, and bound to attract bugs during the maintenance cycle. In addition, it is obviously inefficient to always read the whole DB and reprocess all entries, even though nothing has changed.

I can think of a couple of meaningful optimizations to the above procedure, but my point is, I don't want to have to do manually what looks like a feature that could come out of the box: **The replication of a set of tables into memory of a process to speed up read access**.

I guess if I went ORM and used nhibernate etc., I could get something like that in addition to the ORM layer (by means of caching and eager loading).

Now if I don't want the ORM part, just the replication of the lower relational level, is there anything that I can just switch on?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the metadata and make something generic which can load any table into some kind of structure you like or simply use an ADO.NET [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb0sdh0b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Also, instead of reloading your data on a timer even when it hasn't changed, you can subscribe to changes using [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx)

Comment: can you share a sample link of sql dependency with C# pls

Comment: @StackOverflowUser http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @StackOverflowUser http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7(v=vs.80).aspx